# Is there an easier way to replace files in XCode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Whenever I need to replace a file in my projects, I always have to select the ones I want to replace in the project, delete them, then drag the new files into the project.

This becomes a real pain when I'm changing out many resources, for example, if I'm replacing all the art in the project or changing out plists of data.

I've looked in the preferences but could not find any sort of "Prompt to replace" or similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO the easiest way is to replace files in Finder or Terminal. AFAIK xCode doesn't supports replacing.

Comment: Hated.  Thanks, at least I know now for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight all the files you want to replace, and set Identity and Type > Location to "Relative to Project". Then you can replace files in the Finder and Xcode keeps working. Only need to do it once per file.

Some file types, like Info.plist, and asset catalogs, will make the compile throw errors if you set their location to relative to project. Swift files work fine though.

[image]

Comment: If you have nested folders (groups technically) the location value doesn't auto-apply to child files so you have to manually set it on them too.

Answer (score 0):

XCode gives you no way to replace the file, wither you can, delete the files and add by dargging again, or
Other option is to just replace the files with newer ones using Finder Window, and go to XCode Window, XCode will certenly give you a message that "File named xyz.* is disappeared, do you want to resave it, bla bla bla...", You just need to  close it, dont resave it, it will just reload the file from the window, And if in case XCode doesn't show any disappear message, it will just reload the new file with the same name...